# Expected value of tossing a coin n times

Tags: probability

Ok, so I know that if we toss a coin once we get it's expected value as 0.5. We can do the probability distribution of X and show that for one coin tossed twice we get it's expected value as 1.
So in general expected value E(X)=0.5n
How do I know that I should use the formula that E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)

Similarly the product of the number of points when when n dices are thrown is E(XY)=E(X)*E(Y)
This formula seems easy but how do I know how and when I have to use it ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If you are asked for the expectation of a sum, of course you use the formula for the expectation of a sum.  Similarly, if you are asked for the expectation of a product, you use the formula for the expectation of a product.  Worth noting:  the sum formula holds even if $X,Y$ are dependent, but the product formula requires $X,Y$ to be independent.

Comment: The sum rule and product rule is obvious when a die is used(since you want to find the sum and product of the digits). But when a coin is tossed what analogy do you use. Why is it only sum and not product to get 0.5n

Comment: Well, let $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ toss is $H$ and $0$ if it is $T$.  Then the number of Heads you get is the sum of the $X_i$.

Comment: I mean when I toss a coin n times how do I know I have to use the formula E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y). Why shouldn't I use E(XY) formula?

Comment: @NigelGoveas. A coin doesn't immediately seem to create a numeric result.  Maybe the analogy is to label the head with a 1 and the tail with a zero, then it is a 2-sided dice (or die).  Does that help?

Comment: You need to say what your variable is.  If you set $H=1$, $T=0$ as I did then your total is literally the sum, it's not the product.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mention, the expected value of $X$ is the average value of $X$, weighted by the likelihood of its various possible
values. Symbolically,
$E[X] = \Sigma_x \space x * Pr(X = x)$

where the sum is over all values taken by X with positive probability.

The expected value of the sum of several random variables is equal to the sum of their expectations, e.g.,
$E[X+Y] = E[X]+ E[Y] $

On the other hand, the expected value of the product of two random variables is not necessarily the
product of the expected values. For example, if they tend to be “large” at the same time, and “small” at
the same time, $E[XY] > E[X]⋅E[Y]$, while if one tends to be large when the other is small,
$E[XY] < E[X]⋅E[Y]$. However, in the special case in which X and Y are independent, equality does
hold: $E[XY] = E[X]⋅E[Y].$

Not sure that is exactly what you asked to be honest but it may help.

Comment: https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/weber/emp/_session_0/Probability.pdf

Comment: I mean when I toss a coin n times how do I know I have to use the formula E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y). Why shouldn't I use E(XY) formula?